# How do I upload this messy data to Snowflake?

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to bulk-upload some data to a Snowflake database.  To do this, you write the data out to a CSV file, PUT it to the stage, then COPY FROM the data from the CSV to the table.  (The documentation claims it supports other file types, but when I tried using Avro it errored out on me saying "AVRO file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array. Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column", so it looks like I'm stuck with CSV.)

The problem is, I have some string data that's messy enough to be problematic for CSV files, and I haven't figured out what's the right setting to make it upload correctly.

If my schema looks like (int, string, int, int, int) and my first record looks like so:

```
Int1: 1
Str1: Hey look I'm, really
      messy for CSV \files!
Int2: 1
Int3: 28
Int4: 99
```

I haven't been able to figure out any way to upload this that doesn't error out saying that it's expecting 5 columns but only finding 3.  (Note that there is a comma, a newline, and a backslash in there!)  According to [the type format documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-csv) it looks like there should be a way to make this work with some combination of the `ESCAPE` and `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY` properties, but no matter what I do I seem to keep hitting the same error.

How should my data be formatted, and how should my data format be specified to Snowflake, so that it will accept this record and parse it correctly on the COPY FROM operation?

Comment: Given your comment on Avro, try loading Avro into a table with only one column of type `variant` (there's also https://www.snowflake.com/blog/schema-detection-public-preview/, but for now just try one column)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Loading into a table with only one column is not what I'm trying to do.  The table already exists, with a pre-existing schema, and I have data that matches that schema.  `INFER_SCHEMA` looks interesting, but it doesn't look like it works with `COPY`; the documentation looks like it's about creating new tables.

Comment: But first, I want to see if Avro would help you here - can you try that? We can solve that other problem in a new question, if Avro with one col works for you.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa No, changing the schema of the destination table *categorically will not work* for the problem I'm trying to solve.  Let's take that completely off the table and work on the question I actually asked, please?

Comment: Your csv file needs to be in a format where it is possible to determine what is a field and what is a record. So if your row delimiter is a new line character and you also have this character in the middle of a field then that field needs to be surrounded by, for example, quotes. There is no “magical” solution that allows a system to determine that a new line character should sometimes be a row delimiter and sometimes not

Comment: BTW what I think Felipe was suggesting load each source row into a single column in a temporary table and from there you can use all the SQL functions, stored proc code, etc that Snowflake makes available to clean up your data and copy it into your final table, split into the correct columns

Comment: Hey @MasonWheeler I know you are closed to this option, but this answer might prove useful if you're willing to try it https://stackoverflow.com/a/73130982/132438

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I'm closed to changing the schema of the destination table, specifically.  If `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME` will let me avoid that and use Avro files I'd be open to trying it.

Comment: I thought you were closed off to discussing alternative approaches when you told me `Let's take that completely off the table and work on the question I actually asked, please?`. But that's ok, hopefully the question/answer I left you on  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73130982/132438 helps. If it does, please upvote.

Comment: Let us know if Felipe's answer works because the alternative is not fun. It would require reading entire lines (no column delimiter) as a row, aggregating rows without column names together and concatenating them, and separating `:` and then aggregating the rows into a single row per set of columns. This would only be a last resort, so let us know if Felipe's approach works for you.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa [It gets worse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73139898/why-is-snowflake-having-trouble-parsing-this-avro-file)  I create what appears to be a perfectly valid Avro file, but Snowflake can't read it and doesn't give any good explanation as to why.

Comment: Looking at the new question, everything went alright with avro?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Yeah, eventually.