# How to load Parquet/AVRO into multiple columns in Snowflake with schema auto detection?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro, parquet

When trying to load a Parquet/AVRO file into a Snowflake table I get the error:

> PARQUET file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array. Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column.

But I don't want to load these files into a new one column table — I need the `COPY` command to match the columns of the existing table.

What can I do to get schema auto detection?

Comment: question inspired by `but when I tried using Avro it errored out on me saying "AVRO file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array. Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column"` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73130570/how-do-i-upload-this-messy-data-to-snowflake

Answer (score 3):

Good news, that error message is outdated, as now Snowflake supports schema detection and `COPY INTO` multiple columns.

To reproduce the error:

```sql
create or replace table hits3 (
    WatchID BIGINT,
    JavaEnable SMALLINT,
    Title TEXT
);

copy into hits3
from @temp.public.my_ext_stage/files/
file_format = (type = parquet);

-- PARQUET file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array.
-- Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column.
```

To fix the error and have Snowflake match the columns from the table and Parquet/AVRO files just add the option `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME=CASE_INSENSITIVE` (or `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME=CASE_SENSITIVE`):

```sql
copy into hits3
from @temp.public.my_ext_stage/files/
file_format = (type = parquet)
match_by_column_name = case_insensitive;
```

Docs:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-overview.html?#detection-of-column-definitions-in-staged-semi-structured-data-files

Answer (score 0):

I had a `parquet` file with a special character(##) in the column header. I could not load the file by specifying the column names. So I had to load the file with the `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME` option.

In order to load the `parquet` file I have used the following command:

```
--COPY into table
copy into dbo.Table_name
FROM '@AZURE_STAGE/File_Name.parquet'
file_format=(type='parquet')
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME ='CASE_INSENSITIVE'
;
```

Comment: thats a different answer of what was asked