# Why is Snowflake having trouble parsing this Avro file?

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro

I'm trying to bulk-load data into Snowflake with an Avro file.  I'm able to create the file and PUT it to a Snowflake stage, but when I run the command

```
copy into MyTable from '@%"MyTable"/LinkTypes.avro' file_format = (type = avro) match_by_column_name = case_insensitive;
```

it errors out on me:

> 100084 (22P02): Error parsing AVRO: not an AVRO file (bad magic)

Looking at this file in a hex editor, I don't notice anything particularly bad about it.  I'm able to read it with the same library that created it (`Microsoft.Avro.Core` from NuGet) and it loads just fine in [this random online Avro viewer](https://zymeworks.github.io/avro-viewer/) I googled up.  But for whatever reason, Snowflake can't read it.

[The file can be found here.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnODSQgCtamYgat0MkblYwdR9bZQdQ?e=KFQ44J)  My Avro data generation routine is below.  Anyone have any idea what's wrong with it and how to fix it?

```
public void Write(string name, IDataReader data, DataDictionary dict)
{
    using var stream = OpenFileStream(name); // returns a FileStream; assume this works
    var schema = BuildAvroSchema(dict.GetSchema(name)); // returns a JSON string describing the schema; assume this works
    using var writer = AvroContainer.CreateGenericWriter(schema, stream, Codec.Deflate);
    var serializer = AvroSerializer.CreateGeneric(schema);
    WriteReader(reader, writer, stream, serializer.WriterSchema);
}

private static void WriteReader(IDataReader reader, IAvroWriter<object> writer, Stream stream, TypeSchema schema)
{
    using var sw = new SequentialWriter<object>(writer, 1024);
    var rec = new AvroRecord(schema);
    var len = reader.FieldCount;
    var buffer = new object[len];
    var names = Enumerable.Range(0, len).Select(i => reader.GetName(i)).ToArray();
    while (reader.Read()) {
        reader.GetValues(buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            var value = buffer[i];
            if (value is DateTime dt) {
                value = dt.Ticks;
            }
            rec[names[i]] = value == DBNull.Value ? null : value;
        }
        sw.Write(rec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded you avro file into a stage, and I'm able to load the data without any error.

```
create table testavro (id number, type varchar);
    
copy into testavro from @mystage/LinkTypes.avro file_format = (type = avro) match_by_column_name = case_insensitive;
    
select * from testavro;

+----+-----------+
| ID |   TYPE    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Linked    |
|  3 | Duplicate |
+----+-----------+

ls @mystage;

+---------------------------+------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|           name            | size |               md5                |         last_modified         |
+---------------------------+------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| mystage/LinkTypes.avro.gz |  208 | 14747c0a8e9ab98cbd942feef5ef2702 | Wed, 27 Jul 2022 15:03:48 GMT |
+---------------------------+------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

So I think you should re-upload your file.

Comment: ...that just raises further questions.  Thanks for verifying, I'll look into it.  BTW can you post the result of a `LIST` operation showing this file?

Comment: Works for me too. When I do an `ls` on the stage, the file reports as 192 bytes with an MD5 of `8272b0b2e909634eff9010e21402bfe4`

Comment: I think the file was just corrupted when loading.

Comment: @MasonWheeler and I updated my answer with the output of LS

Comment: I would have expected to get the same MD5, but I clearly the gzipping process is not deterministic. My file works too but the gzipping made it slightly smaller at 192 bytes.

Comment: OK, that's very strange.  Gokhan reports a size of 208, Greg reports 192, and my Snowflake reports a size of 32!  Original file size is 207 bytes.  Yeah, something's definitely going wrong with the upload on my end.

Comment: @MasonWheeler have you tried to delete and upload it again? I am sure that it will fi the issue

Comment: ...and there's the problem.  I had an old, incorrectly-written version of the file already in there and I didn't have `overwrite=true` in my `PUT` command, so it was never getting replaced by the new one.  Thanks for the help!